# EXCEL How to concat values from multiple rows in a single row on another worksheet?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have two columns:

```
ID country
1  spain
1  france
1  sweeden
2  mexico
```

how to concat all the countries with ID 1 and send them to another column like this

```
ID2 country2
1   spainfrancesweeden
```

How to do this with an excel formula instead of a VBA code.

I tried this:

`=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(A18; Hoja2!A19:Hoja2!B24; 2; 1); " ";VLOOKUP(A18; Hoja2!A19:Hoja2!B24; 2; 0))`

But it only gets two results (but there are 3)

Layout of sheet:

[image]

Comment: Could you show the layout of your sheet? Maybe include something you've already tried?

Comment: If you have Excel 365, check [TEXTJOIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and [CONCAT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Also, some help in https://exceljet.net/blog/concat-textjoin

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/rQSMG8N.png

Answer (score 0):

Do convert your data to table and insert pivot table, on the screen of create pivot table check the option add this data to the data model, now go to pivot table fields and right click on the table name and click on add measure. There would be a window opened in the name of Measure in which you put the measure name and value description as per your choice. Now come to formula area which would start with = sign there you type below formula concatenatex(table1,table1[country],","). Now one additional function would had created in the area of pivot table fields. Now you can drag id into rows and drag the created function into Values. It would show the desired result as follows.,

Row Lables|Joincountry
1                   |Spain,France,Sweedan
2                   |Mexico

Hope this is order and would help you.

[!
[result][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5exQH.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5exQH.jpg)